# Set difference of packages installed on 2 machines

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, package-info

Given two machines:

- ServerA
- ServerB

which tool best outputs a "set", `diff`-like view of packages installed:

- Only on ServerA
- Only on ServerB
- On both machines

Answer (score 8):

I just coded this script, which compares also package versions (if you don't need versions, then what ændrük posted is better):

https://github.com/lepe/scripts/blob/master/compare_ubuntu_apt.pl

**Usage:**

1) Generate package list in both computers, like:

```
apt --installed list | tail -n+2 > that_server.lst
```

2) Execute the perl script:

```
./compare_ubuntu_apt.pl this_server.lst that_server.lst
```

**Results: (example)**

```
----------------------------------
 DIFFERENCES 
----------------------------------
 @ apparmor : 2.8.95~2430-0ubuntu5.2 -> 2.8.95~2430-0ubuntu5.3
 @ apt : 1.0.1ubuntu2.8 -> 1.0.1ubuntu2.10
 @ apt-transport-https : 1.0.1ubuntu2.8 -> 1.0.1ubuntu2.10
 @ apt-utils : 1.0.1ubuntu2.8 -> 1.0.1ubuntu2.10
 @ base-files : 7.2ubuntu5.2 -> 7.2ubuntu5.3
 @ bash-completion : 1:2.1-4 -> 1:2.1-4ubuntu0.1
----------------------------------
 MISSING IN this_server.lst
----------------------------------
 + acl : 2.2.52-1
 + acpid : 1:2.0.21-1ubuntu2
 + apport : 2.14.1-0ubuntu3.11
 + apport-symptoms : 0.20
 + at : 3.1.14-1ubuntu1
 + at-spi2-core : 2.10.2.is.2.10.1-0ubuntu1
 + attr : 1:2.4.47-1ubuntu1
 + autotools-dev : 20130810.1
----------------------------------
 MISSING IN that_server.lst
----------------------------------
 - apcupsd : 3.14.10-2build1
 - apcupsd-doc : 3.14.10-2build1
 - beep : 1.3-3
 - btrfs-tools : 3.12-1
 - discover : 2.1.2-5.2ubuntu1
```

Comment: Your script doesn't seems to work for me: I get this:::::    Use of uninitialized value $missing{"\n"} in concatenation (.) or string at ./compare_apt.pl line 82.
 - 
 :

Comment: I updated the script. It seems that the second list passed as argument contained an unexpected `new line` character. Now it should work fine.

Answer (score 7):

1. Get the [list of all packages](https://askubuntu.com/q/17823/1859) for each machine as text files:

   ```
   $ ssh server-a dpkg --get-selections | grep '\binstall$' | cut -f 1 > server-a.txt
   $ ssh server-b dpkg --get-selections | grep '\binstall$' | cut -f 1 > server-b.txt
   ```
2. Use [shell "set operations"](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/set-operations-in-unix-shell-simplified/) to generate the desired results:

   ```
   $ comm -12 <(sort server-a.txt) <(sort server-b.txt) > both.txt
   $ comm -23 <(sort server-a.txt) <(sort server-b.txt) > only-server-a.txt
   $ comm -13 <(sort server-a.txt) <(sort server-b.txt) > only-server-b.txt
   ```
3. Review how many packages are in each set:

   ```
   $ wc -l *.txt
     2238 both.txt
      948 only-server-a.txt
       89 only-server-b.txt
     3186 server-a.txt
     2327 server-b.txt
     8788 total
   ```

Comment: Note that **no** space between the `<` and `(` is important for #2 to work properly.

Comment: [Here](https://www.unixtutorial.org/2014/09/how-to-use-dpkg-to-compare-two-linux-servers/) is another similar way using `diff`.

Comment: [Updated link](https://www.unixtutorial.org/how-to-use-dpkg-to-compare-two-linux-servers/) for using `diff`