# Triple-boot get list of missing packages on different partition

Tags: dual-boot, software-installation, dpkg

### Background

I had a dual-boot Windows 10/Ubuntu 16.04 system. Then I made it triple boot with 18.04. Then I added Lubuntu 16.04 within Vitualbox VM inside Ubuntu 16.04 system.

Somewhere along the way I got lost and deleted `/usr` instead of `usr`. Then thinking `18.04` was freshly synced to `16.04` I copied those files over `/usr` and ended up with a Frankenstein 16.04/18.04.

So I created a live USB 16.04.4 and from that copied over the `/usr` directory. As luck would have it I ended up with a 16.04.4/16.04.5 hybrid with some 18.04 mixed in.

My `apt` was broken but `dpkg` still worked so I used it to reinstall `apt` but it was yet a different version.

I wiped my 18.04 partition and installed a fresh copy of 16.04.5. I installed some random applications like `conky`, `dialog`, `gimp`, `vnstat`, `yad` and maybe a couple of others.

Because I can still mount my old 16.04 partition how can I get a list of packages (without libraries and linux kernels) that still need to be installed on my new 16.04 partition?

Answer (score 1):

### The power of `dpkg`, `diff` and `grep`

My answer is based on this Q&A: [Set difference of packages installed on 2 machines](https://askubuntu.com/questions/344226/set-difference-of-packages-installed-on-2-machines). The differences are:

- There are two different partitions not two different servers
- `apt` is broken in my old 16.04 partition, so `dpkg` is used instead

I mounted my old 16.04 partition as `/mnt/old` and typed the following:

```
/mnt/old$ dpkg --admindir=var/lib/dpkg --get-selections|sort > ~/installed-old
/mnt/old$ dpkg --admindir=/var/lib/dpkg --get-selections|sort > ~/installed-new
/mnt/old$ diff -u ~/installed-old ~/installed-new > ~/compare-old-new
/mnt/old$ cat ~/compare-old-new | grep '^-' | grep -v -e '^-lib' -e '^-linux' | wc -l
257
```

So there are potentially 257 packages that need to be reinstalled but many of them will be auto-installed by a package that depends on them.

### What the list looks like

Here's a snippet of the list when the command `cat ~/compare-old-new | grep '^-' | grep -v -e '^-lib' -e '^-linux'` is used:

```
-mesa-utils                 install
-mesa-vdpau-drivers:amd64   install
-milou                      install
-mkusb-common               install
-mkusb                      install
-mkusb-nox                  install
-module-init-tools          install
-mutter-common              install
-mutter                     install
-mysql-common               install
-nasm                       install
-nautilus-hide              install
-nautilus-image-converter   install
-ntrack-module-libnl-0      deinstall
-nvidia-384                 deinstall
-nvidia-390                 deinstall
-nvidia-opencl-icd-384      deinstall
-nvidia-opencl-icd-390      deinstall
-nvidia-prime               deinstall
-nvidia-settings            deinstall
-nvme-cli                   install
-ocl-icd-libopencl1:amd64   install
-oracle-java8-installer     install
-oracle-java8-set-default   install
-oxideqt-codecs:amd64       install
-oxygen5-icon-theme         deinstall
-pavucontrol                install
-peek                       install
```

Most of the snipped are packages installed to answer a question in **Ask Ubuntu**. From this snippet I only need to reinstall: `mesa-utils`, `mutter`, `nvme-cli`, `pavucontrol` and `peek`.

Packages branded `deinstall` can be ignored: [dpkg --get-selections shows packages marked "deinstall"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/165951/dpkg-get-selections-shows-packages-marked-deinstall)